# Cannot mount visible NSF share

Tags: networking, server, mount, nfs

I have the following exports file:

```
/Filme 192.168.2.0/24(rw,sync,no_root_squash,no_all_squash)
```

This runs on the `192.168.2.70` machine. My IP is `192.168.2.103`.

From my local machine I do the following:

```
$ sudo showmount -e 192.168.2.70                 
Export list for 192.168.2.70:
/Filme 192.168.2.0/24

$ sudo mount -t nfs -v -v 192.268.2.70:/Filme /mnt
mount.nfs: Failed to resolve server 192.268.2.70: Name or service not known
```

I can't figure this out. It's an IP. How can it not resolve it?

Comment: I can't believe this.... I've been troubleshooting this for hours.... Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## TL;DR

You wrote `192.268` instead of `192.168`.

Therefore the server will never be found.

(At least, not unless the rest of your network also uses `192.268`)

## a *brief* summary on network masks

Usually you use `255.255.255.0`. This basically tells your network to take the first three "chunks" of your IP address to identify the network, and that the last chunk has 256 possible values (including `0`).

If you used `255.255.255.252`, you'd have four usable IP addresses.

And, if you used `255.255.255.255`, you'd have one. This is really only useful on loopback addresses. Here's a [forum post](http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1427419) explaining why.

And here's a description of the subnet mask from Microsoft:

> A subnet mask is used to divide an IP address into two parts. One part identifies the host (computer), the other part identifies the network to which it belongs. (from https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/164015/understanding-tcp-ip-addressing-and-subnetting-basics)